# How to convert a file to a Int-Array

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I have a very basic programm, it takes a file as input and outputs it again.

```
    private void GetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ReadFile.Filter = "Txt File (*.txt)|*.txt";

            DialogResult result = ReadFile.ShowDialog();
            string file = ReadFile.FileName;
    }
```

Now i want to convert this file to an int-Array

The .txt file looks like the following:

```
1: 100
2: 120
3: 121
4: 323
.
. 
.
94: 400
95: 132
96: 42 
0:
1:
2:
```

i only need the second number in every line

how  can i convert such file to an array?

Comment: You only need the second number from every line? So 00, 20, 21? Or 0, 2, 2?

Comment: i meant i only need the number after the ":"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *Linq*

```
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;

   ......

   int[] array = File
     .ReadLines(file)
     .Select(line => line.Substring(line.IndexOf(':') + 1))
     .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
     .Select(line => int.Parse(line))
     .ToArray();
```